# When the child shall play at the hole of the asp, will it be newly created or re-created?

Tags: eschatology

The Bible tells us that the elements will melt to form the renewed earth. Since neither the physical world, nor this world's animals + plants can apprehend the Good News, but the eath is to be renewed, why would the animals and plants not be renewed? The verse that comes to mind is the one where "the lion will lie down with the lamb, and the child will play at the hole of the asp". So there will be animals in the renewed earth~  ~so my question is will we have this world's animals living in the new earth or will God create different animals?   ((and where would this world's animals go to, in either case, when we enter the renewed world?))

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is incoherent.  Please review [this guidance](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and make your question clear.

Comment: It is clear enough to me. The Bible appears to say that the earth as we know it now will disappear or, more literally, "the elements being intensely hot will be dissolved" (2 Peter 3:10). Animals could not survive in such conditions, and yet the Bible also says that known animals will be living in peace with each other and people, which would imply that animals will appear again at some point. Question is, how is that supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this short explanation puts things in a whole new perspective: https://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/earth-destroyed/

It also answers the question "*Doesn't the Bible teach that the earth will be burned in fire?*"

The explanation does take some terms figuratively, so how can that be justified? Sometimes the context will show that a literal meaning doesn't fit. For example, where Noah by his faith "condemned the world" (Hebrews 11:7) and everyone who "wants to be a friend of the world is making himself an enemy of God (James 4:4).  Sometimes, the Bible gives a literal explanation. In Daniel 2:35,44-45 God's Kingdom is represented by a mountain. Therefore, you can take that sometimes, a "mountain" can mean "God's Kingdom", which is a specially arranged government as you'll see in those verses, that is in opposition to governments of this world, as explained through the dream.

It seems sensible, then, to conclude that the animals we know now will be there, because the destruction of the earth as Peter mentions it, is not aimed at the animals, but at the worldwide human society (see article). There may be a re-creation of animals that have gone extinct due to mankind's mismanagement of the earth, but the details will probably reveal themselves as and when that time comes.

Comment: There is almost no indication given in the bible of the physical state beyond the return of the Lord. Jesus says in the resurrection they shall neither marry nor be given in marriage but be as the angels of God, but I cannot see any grounds for being specific about anything else, myself. 'It seems sensible to conclude' is an opinion of your own and 'there may be' has no certainty. Your link does not actually cover the question in point.

Comment: Mind that Jesus was replying to "Sadducees, who say there is no resurrection" (Matthew 22:23). There, Jesus first pointed out that they "know neither the Scriptures nor the power of God". It makes all the difference whether or not the environment in which animals can survive will continue or stop to exist at some point. Final paragraph is not opinion, but a conclusion that perhaps should be supported by further arguments and Scriptural evidence, such as God's purpose for the earth and the futility of resistance against what he has determined to do (Genesis 1:28; Job 23:13; Proverbs 21:30).

Comment: It may be that what is to come cannot be conveyed. Eye hath not see nor ear heard nor hath it entered into the heart of man to conceive what God hath laid up for them that wait for him/love him. (NT/OT). Isaiah 11:6 is maybe the clearest image given, but is it to be seen physically ? It was a good question. I might re-ask it in Biblical Hermeneutics. (+1)